# Problem getting data from a different deployed contract - Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I've been working on the cryptozombies tutorial and now i want to go further but when trying to deploy the contract on REMIX to test it i'm having problems. I get:

`transact to ZombieFeeding.feedOnKitty errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.`

Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.` error. 
The code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./zombiefactory.sol";

contract KittyInterface {
    function getKitty(uint256 _id) external view returns (
       bool isGestating,
       bool isReady,
       uint256 cooldownIndex,
       uint256 nextActionAt,
       uint256 siringWithId,
       uint256 birthTime,
       uint256 matronId,
       uint256 sireId,
       uint256 generation,
       uint256 genes
     );
}

contract ZombieFeeding is ZombieFactory {

KittyInterface kittyContract;

    modifier onlyOwnerOf(uint _zombieId) {
        require(msg.sender == zombieToOwner[_zombieId]);
        _;
    }

    function setKittyContractAddress(address _address) external onlyOwner {
        kittyContract = KittyInterface(_address); //0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d
    }

    function _triggerCooldown(Zombie storage _zombie) internal {
        _zombie.readyTime = uint32(now + cooldownTime);
    }

    function _isReady(Zombie storage _zombie) internal view returns (bool) {
        return (_zombie.readyTime <= now);
    }

    function feedAndMultiply(uint _zombieId, uint _targetDna, string   _species) internal onlyOwnerOf(_zombieId) {
        Zombie storage myZombie = zombies[_zombieId];
        require(_isReady(myZombie));
        _targetDna = _targetDna % dnaModulus;
        uint newDna = (myZombie.dna + _targetDna) / 2;
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_species)) == keccak256("kitty")) {
            newDna = newDna - newDna % 100 + 99;
        }
        _createZombie("NoName", newDna);
        _triggerCooldown(myZombie);
    }

    function feedOnKitty(uint _zombieId, uint _kittyId ) public {
       uint kittyDna;// = 456127291358119496194667091109459857780766667351016867864478616867222987;
       (,,,,,,,,,kittyDna) = kittyContract.getKitty(_kittyId);
       feedAndMultiply(_zombieId, kittyDna, "kitty");
    }
}
```

And after debugging I've noticed that if i set the kittyDna variable to something by myself instead of using the `(,,,,,,,,,kittyDna) = kittyContract.getKitty(_kittyId);` line then everything works. My guess is that the way i am implementing the Kitty interface is wrong? BTW I'm not using the mainnet. What i want to do is get the `genes` value from the `cryptokitties getKitty` contracts function. Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the cryptokitties data is not there if you aren't using main net. Cryptokitties are only deployed to mainnet and tested on ropsten.

I suspect the cryptozombies tutorial was assuming the contract was on main net.

I think you might benefit from using revert messages, available in remix.

Comment: Cool! I had a suspicion that it was because I'm not on the mainnet, since this is just something for learning solidity I've decided to generate a random kittyDna. Thanks !